# Passing variable into onclick function in Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, onclick, google-maps-markers, infowindow

I've got code involving Google markers. I want to create a button inside infowindow where when you click on it, it calls a function. But the variable I'm passing into it isn't recognised. And when I use Chrome's console, it shows the error:

roadside_parking_adjust:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: marker_lat is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (roadside_parking_adjust:1)

Here's my code:

```
marker2.addListener('click', function() {
    var marker_lat = this.getPosition().lat();
    var marker_lng = this.getPosition().lng();

    var save_coord_btn = "<input type='button' onClick='saveCoordinates(marker_lat, marker_lng, 12345)' class='btn' value='儲存經緯度'></input>";

    infowindow.setContent("<div style='text-align:center;'>"+save_coord_btn+"</div>");
    infowindow.open(map, this);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the info window content is displayed on the map, the `onClick` handler won't have access to the variables defined at the top of the marker click handler (`marker_lat` and `marker_lng`).

So instead of

```
"... onClick='saveCoordinates(marker_lat, marker_lng, 12345)' ..."
```

concatenate the values of `marker_lat` and `marker_lng` to the `save_coord_btn` string like this:

```
"... onClick='saveCoordinates(" + marker_lat + "," + marker_lng + ", 12345) ...'
```

or you could use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) like this:

```
`... onClick='saveCoordinates(${marker_lat}, ${marker_lng}, 12345)' ...`
```

Take a look at [this JSBin](http://jsbin.com/wekimak/4/edit?js,output) for a working example.